# Share folder structure for projects

Tags: windows, security, shared-folders

I am trying to figure out a way to set up a share drive that will allow a manufacturing shop to restrict access depending whether they work in the office or on the shop floor.

The way they want to do it is to have all of the folder inside of a project number but restrict sales and financial data so the shop can't access it. The only way I know how to do it is to create a shop folder and an office folder with the project folders listed in both directories. They want to copy the folders when they have a new project but that destroys the security and I don't have the time to go through and change the security of every folder each time they copy the folder structure to create a new project.

Do you have any ideas or is there software out there for like project management to have a file structure that allows them to do what they want to do?

**Example**:

```
>> Company share drive
    >>> Project 1000
       >>>> Photos (shop and office access)
       >>>> Sales (Office only)
```

This isn't the exact structure just giving an example to make sure I am making sense. They want to copy and paste a folder "template" and change the name of the project while keeping the security. There's not enough time in this world to manage a share drive like this and I want to redo their share folders.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Windows / Linux / Mac ?

Comment: Sorry Its a Windows Server

Comment: One idea would be to use a relative symbolic link to point to the common folder, zip up the whole structure, and unzip into another folder to recreate the structure. You need a zip program that has a parameter for storing symlinks and not to follow the symlinked folders, or the files will be stored twice.

Comment: so I would create the security settings on the sub folders of a template and I would use a zip program like you mentioned to compress the folders. Then when they need to create a new folder for a new project they would just unzip it and rename the folder and it will maintain the security settings?

Comment: Yes, if it works for you.

Comment: Can you just copy the template folders with permissions? In cmd, you can `robocopy \\path\to\template \\path\to\destination /e /sec`. Give them a little batch file or something to run that does it for them. Otherwise, you could create a script to just fix the folder permissions daily if they're all the same